# Edit Live Running PHP Script

Tags: php, linux, shell, loops

Suppose I have a PHP script, `somescript.php` that runs every 5 minutes and takes 5 minutes to run each time. This script has a loop in it like:

```
for($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++ )
{
$variable = "good";
...[rest of code]
}
```

Is it possible to change the value of `$variable` while `somescript.php` is actively running in a way that if before changing the value of `$variable` the loop iteration was at 50, whereas after the change, for iterations 51-100, they will use the new value of `$variable` (ideally within Ubuntu)?

I don't always want the value to change. Suppose after running the script, I realized `$variable` has the wrong value and want to change its value without stopping the script?

Comment: Not quite understand your requirement...can't it be solved by adding `if ($x==50) $variable = "new";` ?

Comment: @slbteam08, I don't always want the value to change. Suppose after running the script, I realized `$variable` has the wrong value and want to change its value without stopping the script?

Comment: I think this cannot be done by variable inside your PHP script. Need to store the state in some external storage like a file or redis and check it during iterations.

Answer (score 1):

If `somescript.php` runs over command line then you can pass in a new variable right into the command in the following way:

```
php /path/to/www/path/to/script.php new_var
```

Then you can access it in your `somescript.php`:

```
$new_var = $argv[0];
for($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++ )
{
    $variable = "good";
    if ($x >= 50){
        $variable = $new_var;
    }
    ...[rest of code]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited question to clarify.  I don't always want the value to change. Suppose after running the script, I realized `$variable` has the wrong value and want to change its value without stopping the script?

Comment: that "realizing" must be drafted in written form. How does `somescript.php` knows about correct value? If it ends up and returns wrong value then you are going to rerun it passing in new variable anyway.